# Storing images in memory - ImageData vs Image Element

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have to download a series of images (e.g 200) from the server and keep these in memory. The two approaches I have tried so far are:

```
let images = []

// in async loop
...

let image = new Image()

image.src = src

let images.push(image);

...

let images.push(image);
```

vs

```
let images = [];
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// in async loop
let image = await loadImage(); // load image from server

canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;

ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

let imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

let images.push(imageData);
```

In both cases I am saving the image elements or imageData objects in an array. Would one method be better than the other in terms of memory consumption, etc?

Comment: ImageElement stores the raw pixels more efficiently but has extra DOM-related stuff and makes an HTTP request each time you set/change the SRC property. ImageData stores the pixels as DataURI, Base64 encoded (33% bigger than the raw binary data) - and some browsers have limitations on how long a DataURI can be.

Comment: Interesting. So in terms of saving memory, it might be better to choose an imageElement rather than ImageData.

Comment: I think it will save you some additional gymnastics with Canvas :)